# How do I do a where query on a SQL column against multiple values?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, arel

This is what my query looks like:

```
Connection.where("invited_user_id = :user_a_id AND inviter_user_id = :user_b_id", user_a_id: self.inviter.try(:id), user_b_id: self.invited.try(:id)).exists?
```

What I would like to do is basically check `invited_user_id` against multiple options, e.g. something like `invited_user_id = [:user1, :user2]`. But that doesn't work.

How can I check to see if the value in the column `invited_user_id` is in either of the variables `:user1`, `:user2` or any other of multiple variables.

Is that possible without using an explicit `OR` approach that's less DRY?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never put values directly in a query, that's not safe. Parameterize your query using the `?` operator.

```
invited_user_ids = [:user1, :user2]
Connection.where("invited_user_id IN (?)", invited_user_ids)
```

Comment: Can you update this query to work in this query: `Connection.where("invited_user_id = :user_a_id AND inviter_user_id = :user_b_id", user_a_id: self.inviter.try(:id), user_b_id: self.invited.try(:id)).exists?`

Comment: Also placeholder conditions is the same as parameterizing with the `?` as you suggest. See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#pure-string-conditions - section 2.2.1 for more info.

Answer (score 2):

The Hash form of `where` accepts array of values, so:

```
Connection.where(invited_user_id: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

That will find all records where `invited_user_id` is any of the values listed in the array.

Comment: Any way to do this in SQL?

Comment: Yes, but that was not your question. `select * from table where invited_user_id IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)`

Comment: My bad. What I meant was, to get it in a format like this: `Connection.where("invited_user_id = :user_a_id AND inviter_user_id = :user_b_id", user_a_id: self.inviter.try(:id), user_b_id: self.invited.try(:id)).exists?` How do I query each of the columns against both `:user_a_id` and `:user_b_id`?